# Which of these methods would be considered best practice?

Tags: jquery

I have an array of data that is returned as a JSON response.  The data will be regularly updated, and will also be accessed very frequently.

The data contains a list of comments/replies for each song on display and is accessed when the user hovers over a particular element, and the specific comment/reply is then rendered to a template.

The list of songs is also dynamically filterable and the array will therefore be constantly updating.

Given the frequent access and updates of this data which of the following would be considered best practice:-

A. Store the whole array in a global variable and constantly manipulate it/access it.

or

B. Store the array in the DOM using jQuery's $.data method and access it that way.

Which would be best and why... If option A please bear in mind that the variable will need to be held in memory throughout the users session.  Also is there anything I need to watch out for in terms of potential memory leaks etc?

EDIT:  Just to provide some more information: On average I would expect the data to be between 2-5kb at any given time.

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far guys, but I would like to get a couple more opinions, before marking it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to have to say **option B** here. While the performance benefits of manipulating a pure array sounds really attractive, from what it sounds like, your usage of the data sort of necessitates relating your data to the individual DOM elements they apply to.

With `$.data`, you're attaching data to the element that they pertain to. Imagine the workflow of your `hover` event:

```
// with option A
$('.song').mouseover(function (e) {
    // read the relevant index value of the data from this element
    // (probably through some attribute?)

    // get the data from the global array

    // show that data on hover
});

// with option B
$('.song').mouseover(function (e) {
    // show the $(this).data() on hover
});
```

It's certainly cleaner, and I can't imagine how you're making your DOM elements remember their associated data in the global array, save from plugging it on the DOM element themselves via an attribute, or having an object reference somewhere.

Secondly, global objects are evil. To some significant, prone-to-argument-and-debate-flamebait extent.

Thirdly, it sounds like your song elements are sorting and filtering on the DOM themselves. If you attach your data via `$.data`, those get sorted and filtered along with the DOM elements without any additional tracking. A song element has to be erased from the DOM? Just call `.remove()` on it --- the associated gets deleted as well. Free functionality!

Lastly, `$.data` is also optimized to prevent circular references and memory leaks as well (correct me if I'm mistaken on that one).

Besides, 2-5kb of data doesn't sound like a whole lot.

Just my two cents.

Comment: Great answer, i'm conviced. You're quite correct, the hover handler will be cleaner if the data is directly tied to the element. Thanks too all who answered.

Comment: Sadly, it looks as though I will have to take the global variable approach, since IE seems to not want to play nicely with the data for some reason.  A real shame since it works beautifully in every other http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896259/why-cant-i-get-nested-array-property-in-ie9

Comment: Looking at your linked question, it looks like you managed to fix it. Syntax problems only, I presume? :D

Comment: Indeed.  Option B it is now... and it works beautifully.  Thanks Richard :-)

Answer (score 2):

A) would be my preferred choice, as you should try to avoid an ever expanding [dom](http://www.artzstudio.com/2009/04/jquery-performance-rules/#limit-dom-manipulation).

[Direct DOM manipulation is rather slow](http://www.tvidesign.co.uk/blog/improve-your-jquery-25-excellent-tips.aspx#tip6), so try to avoid it where possible.

Answer (score 0):

IMO it depends on your JS/JQ code. If it's componentized, keeping each component's data local using `.data` is cleaner. If it isn't, it may not matter, but keeping it in a single location might makes things easier. I haven't run into specific issues using a lot of `.data` attachments, but I may have been lucky.

Have you determined it's absolutely necessary to keep the data on the page at all times? Arbitrary, unbounded increases in page storage would make me a little nervous compared to adding/removing large chunks, which a comment tree could turn in to.

Comment: Unfortunately yes, given the nature of the application the options really are either persistent memory storage with frequent updates or lots of writes/reads to the dom with $.data.  On average I would expect the data to be between 2-5kb at any given time.